# VB.NET Multilingual resource files - work fine in dev - missing in publish

Tags: vb.net, globalization, embedded-resource

My click-once app has english and spanish content. In development, it runs fine with the two resource files I have - named multilingual.en-US.resx &  multilingual.es-MX.resx accordingly. When I publish it looses these resources for referencing. Anyone have any idea why it would do that? The files reside in the root directory for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things you can check:

1. Make sure the build action is set to "Embedded Resource" for those two files. (Click on them in solution explorer and check the properties window.)
2. In the Publish settings for your application, click the "Application Files" button and make sure the resource dlls are set to "Include". If they're not, ClickOnce might not pick them up.